# What does it mean when a generics function has two return types?

Tags: java, generics

I am going through a tutorial and I found this particular code.

```
 private <V> V fromJson(HttpRequest request, Class<V> target) throws IOException {
    Reader reader = request.bufferedReader();
    try {
        return GSON.fromJson(reader, target);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        throw new JsonException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            // Ignored
        }
    }
}
```

I notice that the fromJson function has two return types? I have the basic idea of generics and how it works. What I can't understand is how are two types specified and how will this function know which type to assign the value to when its called.

Comment: It's not two return types, it's one - `V`. The first `<V>` is just how you define a generic method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is only one return type.  The `<V>` declares the `V` generic type parameter (it makes the method generic), and the `V` after that is the actual return type.

Here's [more information on generic methods in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Comment: I would include a tidbit on how the part in angled braces can be used for an upper or lower bound on the generic.